# MySql query not running on the correct database after mysql_select_db

Tags: php, mysql, database

Firstly, I know that this system shouldn't be using mysql_ functions anymore, but it does.

The system is connecting to two databases. Before running a query, it is selecting the correct database on which to run the query using mysql_select_db(). The correct database is 'database2'. The connection to the database itself works, and the mysql_select_db function is returning true/1.

The code works locally but does not work on the server...

Here is an example of a failing query...

```
global $DBtwo;

mysql_select_db('database2', $DBtwo);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table
         (Column1, Column2, Column3)
     VALUES
         ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3')";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $DBtwo);

die(mysql_error());
```

This script returns the following output...

```
Table 'database1.table' doesn't exist
```

The error suggests that the query is being executed on database1, not database2. However database2 is being successfully selected before the query is run.

As mentioned, this error only occurs on the server. Running locally the queries work and the correct databases are used.

Any suggestions or pointers would be very welcome. Cheers.

Comment: You're simply ASSUMING the select_db call succeeded. `mysql_select_db(...) or die(mysql_error($DBtwo))` and note that if you have MULTIPLE db connections open, your error call will be using the last-opened one, since you didn't explicitly list a connection handle. which means you may be checking for errors on the WRONG db handle.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am investigating...

Comment: stop using MySQL and research `MySQLi`as well as/or `PDO`. You can also do well to research using a OOP approach as this issue of getting databases mixed up will be less likely or even impossible to achieve with that code structure.

Comment: You're quite right. The mysql_error() was misleading due to not being passed a resource. My use of connections in general is awful, and you have solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I would love to but unfortunately no-ones paying me to do that :(

Comment: Yeah it sucks, but you should at least be getting paid something that covers your work time as well as covering an additional timescale for backend development and R&D. Even if it's just reading a couple of hours a week, given a month or two you can then gradually salami slice rolling out improvements and fixes and be swimming forward.  It is in your clients/employees interest that you are good at what you do, and that involves reading and practising... Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Marc B solved my problem so credit goes to him.

The mysql_error function was returning misleading info as it was not being passed a resource.

The mysql_select_db was actually working. It gave the impression of not working via a combination of not passing the correct resource to mysql_error. On top of that a mysql_insert_id() was not working for the same reason, leading the function overall to return false.

I now feel stupid, but far less annoyed. Many thanks!

Comment: If this solved your problem then you can also accept it as an answer so other people can benefit from it.